# How to Find All TRUE Conditions and Concatenate Corresponding Variables into New Variable?

Tags: c++, c

```
a = 4
b = 5
c = 7

if (a >= 4){
    text1 = “a is high”;
}
if (b >= 8){
    text2 = “b is high”;
}
if (c >= 6){
    text3 = “c is high”;
}
```

In C or C++, how would I find which of these statements are true (a & c) and create a new variable that concatenates their accompanying variables containing text to produce a result like “a is high and c is high”? The next time the code executes it may find that only **a** is high, or whatever the case may be.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: C?  or C++?  Pick one.  Also, you have a *sequence* of `if` statements, but none of them are *nested*.

Comment: Your description of how to solve the problem sounds plausible, do it exactly like that. Show the code you tried (possibly with pseudo code in comments, where the exact details are not clear to you), please. Also, it is highly recommended to create a [mcve]. Maybe take the [tour].

Comment: Is the test `(c <= 6)` really meant to be `(c >= 6)`?  It seems funny (peculiar) to state `c is high` when you check that it is low enough.  Treating it as a typo would make your expectations work.  Otherwise, more verbiage is needed.

Comment: "C/C++" dose not exist. We handle strings differently in C and C++. It is unclear how to answer you. Or, maybe it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: This is what I am thinking....I will go through all the answers now and thank, vote, and everything...

a = 4
b = 5
c = 7
text1 = ""

if (a >= 4){
text1 = “a is high”;
}
if (b >= 8){

if (Not text1 = ""){
text1 = text1 + " and b is high";}

if (text1 = ""){
text1 = “b is high”;}

}

if (c <= 6){

if (Not text1 = ""){
text1 = text1 + " and c is low";}
if (text1 = ""){
text1 = “c is low”;}

}

Comment: Yunnosch - I will take the tour - my apologies. Thanks for the comments though. I was not looking for a quick answer just some guidance. It helps me learn. 
Leffler - yeah I was just using an example...
Nicky - yup, I was unclear...
Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single variable and keep on appending as you get the required information.

```
string text1;
if (a >= 4)
   text1.append("a is high");    
if (b >= 8)
{
    if(text1.length()!=0)
         text1.append(" and ");
    text1.append("b is high"); 
}    
if (c <= 6)
{
   if(text1.length()!=0)
        text1.append(" and ");
   text1.append("c is high");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is where I was headed. I think I asked (unclearly) before I needed to ask - maybe I got frustrated. LOL This is basically what I came up with as well.
I really appreciate the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Gaurav Sehgal is elegant. Here is another way of writing it-

**C++**

```
string text = "";
if (a >= 4)
   text += "a is high";    
if (b >= 8)
{
    if(text.size() > 0)
         text += " and ";
    text += "b is high"; 
}    
if (c <= 6)
{
   if(text.size() > 0)
        text += " and ";
   text += "c is high";
}
```

**C**

```
char text[buf_size] = {'\0'};
if (a >= 4)
   strcat(text, "a is high");    
if (b >= 8)
{
    if(strlen(text) > 0)
         strcat(text, " and ");
    strcat(text, "b is high");
}    
if (c <= 6)
{
   if(strlen(text) > 0)
         strcat(text, " and ");
    strcat(text, "c is high");
}
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks for both examples. Very appreciated.

Comment: It is my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

create a temporary variable as result.

```
a = 4
b = 5
c = 7
result="";

if (a >= 4){
    result += “a is high”;
}
if (b >= 8){
    if(result==""){
        result += “b is high”;
    }else{
        result += “and b is high”;
    }
}
if (c <= 6){
    if(result==""){
        result += “c is high”;
    }else{
        result += “and c is high”;
    }
}
text1=result
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numeric comparison operators as well as logical AND ("&&"), the following C code finds all true conditions while obviating the need for a new variable as it  efficiently uses **text1, text2** and **text3**.  Note, the result avoids any duplicate output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
int a = 4;
int b = 5;
int c = 7;

char text1[] = "a is high";
char text2[] = "b is high";
char text3[] = "c is high";

if ( a >= 4 && c < 6){
puts(text1);
}

if (b >= 8){
puts(text2);
}


if (c >= 6 && a < 4) {
puts(text3);
}

if( ( a >= 4 ) && ( c >= 6 ) ) {
strcat(text1," and ");
strcat(text1,text3);
puts(text1);
}

return 0;
}
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/4OUaRY)